# What's the meaning of $\hat{f}(\xi)=O(e^{-2\pi a|\xi|})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
The above page is from *Complex Analysis* by Stein.

What's the meaning of $\hat{f}(\xi)=O(e^{-2\pi a|\xi|})$?

Comment: $\exists C, \forall \xi, |\hat{f}(\xi)| \le C e^{-2 \pi a |\xi|}$.  This is what you need for $f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2i \pi \xi z}d\xi$ to converge absolutely for $|\Im(z)| < a$, which implies $f$ is bounded, continuous, smooth, holomorphic, analytic for $|\Im(z)| < a$

Comment: @reuns $\hat f$ is supported in the interval $[-M,M]$, it means the closure of $\{x\in \Bbb R:\hat f(x)\neq 0\}$ is contained in the interval $[-M,M]$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Your text is supposed to be clear : 3.3 is assuming $f(z)=\int_{-M}^M \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2i \pi \xi z}d\xi$ ie. $\hat{f}= 0$ outside of $[-M,M]$. You can start by assuming $\hat{f}$ is bounded, then extend to $\hat{f}$ integrable.